# algebra - basic question on boats and streams

Tags: linear-algebra

Sonal and Deepali started swimming towards each other simultaneously from points A and B respectively situated at two ends of a 96 km long stretch of a river. Destinations of Deepali and Sonal were points A and B respectively. Both of them could swim at 12 kmph in still water. When they started, it was high tide and Sonal swam against the stream. As soon as they met, the tide changed to low tide and then Deepali faced the resistance of the stream. Deepali and Sonal took 7 hr 12 min and 8 hr 34 min to reach their destinations respectively.

1. Find the speed of the stream during low tide.
   (a) 1 kmph (b) 4 kmph (c) 2 kmph (d) Cannot be determined
2. If they had continued to swim back to their respective starting points after reaching their destinations, then where would they have met during the return journey?
   (a) 32 km from A
   (b) 32 km from B
   (c) 72 km from A
   (d) 60 km from B

Source: Question posted in a [forum](http://www.pagalguy.com/discussions/official-quant-thread-for-cat-2011-part-8-25073031?page=370)

I have been practicing aptitude questions . This particular question does not have any answer.

I tried doing it for a good time and ended in two equations having 3 unknowns. 
To me, answers cannot be found. Am I correct or is there any solution for this?

Comment: Swim at 12 kmph?? Wow! And for 96 km!!

Comment: :) leave that, just dummy values. But I am getting more and more convinced now that this cannot be solved with the given information

Comment: It is possible to solve the problem. Are you sure of the 8h34min?

Comment: 8h 34min is what given in the question. Take any value. Could you give pointer towards how we can solve it? With speed each one take before and after meeting, we can get two equations where unknowns are the distance between A and the meeting point, speed of the stream with high tide and speed of the stream with low tide

Comment: We assume that the person who is not swimming against the stream, thus along with it gains that speed?

Comment: I've just seen the web page you linked: the exact value given there is 8h34min2/7, that is $8+34/60+2/420$ hours. Using that value I get 2 kmph as the low tide stream speed. Hint: you can easily obtain that they meet after exactly 4 hours.

Comment: thanks  Aretino. I will now spend more time to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_H$ and $v_L$ be the high tide and low tide stream speed respectively, measured in kmph, and let $t$ be the time (in hours) from the start to their meeting. Up to their meeting, the speed of Sonal is then $12-v_H$, while the speed of Deepali is $12+v_H$.

If you add up the lengths covered by both swimmers up to their meeting you get the whole length of 96 km, so we can write the equation
$$
(12-v_H)t+(12+v_H)t=96.
$$
$v_H$ cancels out so we get $t=4$.
A similar equation can be used for the second part, to get in the end $v_L=2$.